# Show that the linear subspace $Y$ of $X$ generated by : ${\displaystyle\bigcup_{i} A_i}$ is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, reflexive-space

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a reflexive Banach space and $(A_i)_{i\geq 1}$ a sequence of separable subset of $X$.\

Show that the linear subspace $Y$ of $X$ generated by  : 
 ${\displaystyle\bigcup_{i} A_i}$ is closed.

An idea please.

Answer (score 1):

This is surely false. Take $X=\ell^{2}$. Let $(e_i)$ be the usual basis and take $A_i$ to be the one dimensional subspace generated by $e_i$, $i=1,2...$. Then the span of $\cup_i A_i$ is not closed.

For example $\sum \frac 1 i e_i$ belongs to the closure of this span but it does not belong to the span.